# Access Violation Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, winforms, image, printing

I am trying to print an image by `OnPrintPage` event as follows.

```
protected virtual void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = ExportAsMetafile(0);
    CultureInfo current = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Width, (int)e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Height));
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = current;            
}
```

when I tried saving the img by `img.Save("img.png");`, I got the image what I need

But, When I tried to draw this image in `e.Graphics.DrawImage`, it shows the exception as folows
[image]

Can Anyone help me out of this.?

Comment: what if you specify the full path of the destination file?

Comment: sorry, I cant get you.. trippino

Comment: what if you use something like this: `img.Save("D:\\img.png");` ?

Comment: thats not problem man.... its just for testing, i done it.... it saves the image correctly.... but I am unable to draw in graphics.. this is what the problem here

Comment: Your image crashed the printer driver, possibly because you drew it so large.  You'll need to find a better one.

Comment: Hans Passant: I am trying to save it as XPS document...
Other images are all working out fine for me...
"You 'll need to find a better one" --- What should be better?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this(note I got this from msdn)

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\\My Folder\\MyFile.bmp"), ev.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds);
```